# Why does the URL in UI-Router keep resetting?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I'm using AngularJS for the framework of my web application, and UI-Router for nested states. While I'm changing be states in UI-Router, as long as I'm changing between sibling states, the URL gets updated correctly, but when I change to another parent state, the URL becomes:

http://{domain}:{port}/#/

What could be causing it?

Comment: Please post some sample code that you have used

Comment: I think you used otherwise and might possible that your url is mismatch

Answer (score 0):

This won't be a common problem for others, so I'll post what solved the issue in hopes no one gets stuck for as long as I did.

The common URL address for states (UI-Router concept) in my application is

xttp://domain.com/#/{siteId}/state1/state1a (where {siteId} is a variable integer)

The problem here is that when changing between states, siteId cannot be passed along the top level. This means that when a link takes a user from state 1a to state 2a, siteId will not be passed along, and routing will fail.

I solved the issue by putting siteId in a cookie rather than in the URL as a path variable. The common URL address after solving the issue then became:

xttp://domain.com/#/state1/state1a

Simon S.